# Why my update function cannot update record?

Tags: php, sql

I called my update sql every time run the php file and it return true statement but record cannot update perfectly. I want to know that where my code goes wrong? Please help me and I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

This is my php code in `event-listing.php`:

```
$update_event_list = $event->updateeventlist($type = 1);
```

This is my sql statement in `Event.inc.php` :

```
function updateeventlist($type){
            global $db;

            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM "._CONST_TBL_EVENT." WHERE type = ".$type;

            if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt)){
                while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
                {
                    if($rsa['start_date'] < strtotime("now")){
                        $updateEvent = "UPDATE "._CONST_TBL_EVENT." SET type = 2 WHERE id = ".$rsa['id'];
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

I have tried to echo out the statement and it return true statement that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `execute` function after the update query.

```
$rs = $db->Execute($updateEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Query execution missing after your update Query

```
function updateeventlist($type){
            global $db;

            $stmt = "SELECT * FROM "._CONST_TBL_EVENT." WHERE type = ".$type;

            if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt)){
                while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
                {
                    if($rsa['start_date'] < strtotime("now")){
                        $updateEvent = "UPDATE "._CONST_TBL_EVENT." SET type = 2 WHERE id = ".$rsa['id'];
                        $db->Execute($updateEvent);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below are some points that i observed in your code:-

1. You are not executing the update query. You are just making the query as string but not executing.
2. Even if you none of the records is updated or fetched you still get "true", because there is no condition to specify when to return false if it fails.

   ```
       $stmt = "SELECT * FROM "._CONST_TBL_EVENT." WHERE type = ".$type;

       if($rs = $db->Execute($stmt))
       {
        if( $rs has atleast one row rows )
         {
           while($rsa = $rs->FetchRow())
           {
               if($rsa['start_date'] < strtotime("now")){
                   $updateEvent = "UPDATE "._CONST_TBL_EVENT." SET type = 2 WHERE id = ".$rsa['id'];
                   $db->Execute($updateEvent); // this line was missing in you code
               }
           }
         }
         else
        {
               return false;
                // $rsa has empty rows
         }

       }
       else // execution of query fails for any reason
       {
          return false;
       }
   ```